# Pointer deference wrapped in parens in go

Tags: pointers, go

I am learning go coming from JS and trying to wrap my head around pointers.  I understand that if

```
type ListNode struct {
    Val  int
    Next *ListNode
}

a := ListNode{0, null}
b:= &a
```

b would be a pointer to the memory location of a and if

```
b.Val = 15
```

then afterwards a.Val is 15.

I attempted a problem with a linked list, and if l1 represents a pointer to a node in a list, i noticed someone doing this when shifting the pointer.

```
l1 = (*l1).Next
```

but the solution worked if i reformatted them into

```
l1 = l1.Next
```

So it seems that (*l1) is de-referencing the pointer, then re-referencing it again? Am I misinterpreting that? I cannot find any reference to wrapping a deref in parens in the docs or anywhere else online. Thanks for your help

Comment: `l1.Next` is shorthand for `(*l1).Next`.  Here's the quote from [the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors): if the type of x is a defined pointer type and (*x).f is a valid selector expression denoting a field (but not a method), x.f is shorthand for (*x).f

Comment: @MuffinTop Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense. I'll check through the spec more thoroughly next time, I looked for a while and just couldn't find it.